# Woocommerce Products description and attributes based on role

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I already installed the “price based on role” plugin but I can’t find a similar plugin to set alternative descriptions and attibutes based on role, can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any plugin can't provide you this functionality.So could you please elaborate your requirement more, i will provide you custom plugin for the same.

Comment: I gave up, I duplicated all the products with different description and prices. Thanks